# How to remove a zsh keybinding if I don't know what it does?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I disable a keybinding if I don't know what it is or what it's triggering?

I have my `zsh` key mode set to vi-mode, through `bindkey -v`.

To do a history search, I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get to "command mode", and then <kbd>/</kbd> to start the search. However, if I press them too fast, it does something else, but *I don't know what!* I assume `Esc-/` is some keybinding, but I don't know what it is. How do I find this and turn it off?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some searching, I've found the answer:

To discover what `escape sequence` the key combination is triggering, follow [this excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/169930):

`echo "`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>`"`

Which displays, for me, as: `echo "^[/"`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> forces the following key to display as an escape sequence instead of being interpreted. So now we know we're trying to find what is bound to `"^[/"`.

---

To list all zsh key bindings, simply execute `bindkey` with no args:

```
$ bindkey
"^A"-"^C" self-insert
"^D" list-choices
"^E"-"^F" self-insert
"^G" list-expand
"^H" backward-delete-char
...
"^Y"-"^Z" self-insert
"^[" vi-cmd-mode
"^[," _history-complete-newer
"^[/" _history-complete-older   ### <--- Here it is.
"^[M" vi-up-line-or-history
"^[OA" vi-up-line-or-history
...
"^\\\\"-"~" self-insert
"^?" backward-delete-char
"\M-^@"-"\M-^?" self-insert
```

So, having decided that I don't care about `_history-complete-older`, I'm just going to remove it. I added this to my `.zshrc`:

```
# Unbind the escape-/ binding because it gets triggered when I try to do a history search with "/".
bindkey -r "^[/"
```

If, instead, you just want to rebind it to some other key, you might use:

```
bindkey -r "^[/"
bindkey "<some-other-key-combo>" _history-complete-older
```

Comment: You can actually look up a specific key binding by passing it as single argument to `bindkey` without other options: `bindkey '^[/'`.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably

```
% bindkey '^[/'
"^[/" _history-complete-older
%
```

or similar.  And that's how you find out.

### Further reading

- Paul Falstad (2015-12-02). "[ZLE builtins](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Builtins)". *Z Shell Manual*.  5.2.

Answer (score 5):

This question has two parts,

1. how do I find out what the mapping does?
2. how do I unbind the mapping?

#### how do I find out what the mapping does?

as mentioned in other answers

```
bindkey <key_combination>
```

this will print the zle command related to the key combination

#### how do I unbind the mapping?

```
bindkey -r <key_combination>
```

reference - http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html#l95

Comment: Do you know why `bindkey -rp '^'` doesn't have any effect, but `bindkey -rp '^['` and `-rp '^X'` do?

Answer (score 3):

Also related is the `KEYTIMEOUT` setting, which indicates how long ZSH will wait to detect multi-key sequences, minimized by setting:

```
KEYTIMEOUT=1
```

If you're feeling super extreme, you can also remove all the ESC-something binds, so that ZSH has no multi-key sequences it will waste time waiting for following the escape key being pressed.

```
bindkey -rpM viins '^['
bindkey -rpM vicmd '^['
```

Comment: I think multi-key sequences are useful, for example, binding `jk` in vi insert
mode to going to normal mode; you could as well have a little KEYTIMEOUT=20